# extracting values in HTML data

Tags: python, html, regex

I have data in this HTML format in python:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" >
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
```

I would like a way to extract the contents of the value attribute using regular expressions in python.

Comment: my data are like this : <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="asdsadasdasdasd" />

Comment: You definitely want to use regex? You can use a parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but I understand if you want to keep dependencies to a minimum.

Comment: how can i use it to extract values ?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 2):

html can be much more complicated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" >'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
input_tag = soup.find('input')
input_tag['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

With BeautifulSoup, you can use the find method of the `BeautifulSoup` class and extract the value attribute like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
x = """<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" >"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(x)
print soup.find('input')['value']
```